# Controlling a light with two inputs (PIR and a momentary switch)

Tags: python-3

I am new with Python and not sure how to integrate the following. I have a setup where I am trying to control an LED strip for under-counter lighting using python and GPIO-Zero. The PIR activates the lights and stays on for five minutes. During that time I would like to override the PIR timer with the momentary switch to extend the time or keep on until pressed again if needed.

I cannot see how to create this in programming. I am currently calling a function out of a while loop. I really want that button, too. Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# manual color selection
import time
import argparse
import datetime
from rpi_ws281x import *
from gpiozero import Button, LED, MotionSensor
from signal import pause
from time import sleep

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT      = 60      # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN        = 18      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA        = 10      # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 200     # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT     = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL    = 0       # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

#Set color variables to an RGB value initially that will applied. This is a way to color adjust the lights for your conditions.
red = 232   # 232 Original value
green = 163 # 163
blue = 33   # 33

# Time in seconds the strip will be lit
motion_timer = 300

# Button input configuration:
button = Button(4)

# Button color ring configuration:
button_red_led = LED(26, active_high=False)
button_green_led = LED(19, active_high=False)
button_blue_led = LED(13, active_high=False)

# Motion sensor configutation:
pir = Button(17, pull_up=False)

#Current time
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()


# Define functions

#Causes chosen color to wipe over the strip
def colorWipe(strip, color, wait_ms=50):
    """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/2500.0)
        
#test function to understand the workings **** INCOMPLETE *****
def color_rotate():
    for x in range(30):
        button_red
        
        

# Main program logic follows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Process arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--clear', action='store_true', help='clear the display on exit')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.

    strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL)
    # Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).

    strip.begin()

    print ('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
    print('System initialized...', current_time)
    print()
    button_red_led.blink(2, 2)  # Initial red to show startup is off.
    if not args.clear:
        print('Use "-c" argument to clear LEDs on exit')
        
        

    try:

        while True:
            # Time stamp for reference.

            pir.wait_for_press()
            button_red_led.off()
            button_blue_led.on()
            
            # Values are delcared via red, green, blue variables
            colorWipe(strip, Color(red, green, blue))   
            time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            print('The light is ON and the switch status is BLUE: ', time_stamp, "\n")
            sleep(motion_timer)
            
            time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            button_blue_led.off()
            button_red_led.on()
            colorWipe(strip, Color( 0, 0, 0))   # Blank wipe the strip
            print('The light is OFF and the switch status is RED: ', time_stamp, "\n" )
            

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if args.clear:
            colorWipe(strip, Color(0,0,0), 10)
            button_red_led.off()
            button_blue_led.off()
            button_green_led.off()
            print('Program ended, light is off')
```

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: OK. Its a mess.

Comment: Even though this is using a Pi this is a programming question. You need to learn how to design, write and debug your code. I suggest you start with something simpler. Gpiozero has a number of Button examples.

Comment: The first step in any program is to clearly define what it should do, which is unclear from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous post did help me get out of the deep weeds.

I finally worked out a while condition that satisfies the two input requirement. As you know the PIR will activate on any movement. I wanted a momentary press button (I used one of the rugged RGB 16mm switches) to extend an on condition. pir is set to 5 minutes and button is set to 15. There are variables to manage these timers. I created two def functions for each action. The condition is done in the def pir_active(). The 'while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time and not button.is_pressed:' is what finally gave me the button. Works great. There is a lot of extra stuff that I can strip out but it is mainly helpful for structure and troubleshooting.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Under counter light control using strip lights.
# Program by : John L. Peck

import argparse
import datetime
from rpi_ws281x import *
from gpiozero import Button, LED

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT = 13  # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN = 18  # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
LED_FREQ_HZ = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA = 10  # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 200  # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT = False  # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL = 0  # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

# Set color variables to an RGB value initially that will applied. This is a way to color adjust the lights for your conditions.
red = 232  # 232 Original value
green = 163  # 163
blue = 33  # 33

# Time in seconds the strip will be lit
pir_timer = 300  # Seconds
button_timer = 900  # Seconds

# Inputs configuration:
button = Button(4)

# Motion sensor configuration:
pir = Button(17, pull_up=False)

# Button color ring configuration:
button_red_led = LED(26, active_high=False)
button_green_led = LED(19, active_high=False)
button_blue_led = LED(13, active_high=False)

# Current time
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()


# Define functions

# Causes chosen color to wipe over the strip
# noinspection PyShadowingNames
def colorwipe(strip, color):
    """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
        strip.show()
    # time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)


# When button is pressed causes led strip to light for an amount of time as defined by button_timer
def pressed():
    # is_pressed = True
    print('\nSwitch activated')
    beginning_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=button_timer)
    end_time = beginning_time + time_delta
    print('\nBeginning time :', beginning_time)
    print('Time delta     :', time_delta)
    print('End time       :', end_time, "\n")
    print('Waiting...\n')
    button_red_led.off()
    button_green_led.on()
    button_blue_led.off()

    while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time:  # and not button.is_pressed:
        button_red_led.off()
        button_green_led.on()
        button_blue_led.off()
        colorwipe(strip, Color(red, green, blue))

    else:
        button_red_led.on()
        button_green_led.off()
        button_blue_led.off()
        colorwipe(strip, Color(0, 0, 0))
        print(button_timer / 60, 'minute timer ended :', datetime.datetime.now(), '\n')


# When PIR is active cause led strip to light for an amount of time as defined by pir_timer
def pir_active():
    print('\nPIR activated')
    beginning_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=pir_timer)
    end_time = beginning_time + time_delta
    print('\nBeginning time :', beginning_time)
    print('Time delta     :', time_delta)
    print('End time       :', end_time, "\n")
    print('Waiting...\n')

    while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time and not button.is_pressed:
        button_red_led.off()
        button_green_led.off()
        button_blue_led.on()
        colorwipe(strip, Color(red, green, blue))

    else:
        button_red_led.on()
        button_green_led.off()
        button_blue_led.off()
        colorwipe(strip, Color(0, 0, 0))
        print(pir_timer / 60, 'minute timer ended :', datetime.datetime.now(), '\n')
    # return


# Main program logic follows

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Process arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--clear', action='store_true', help='clear the display on exit')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
    strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL)

    # Initialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
    strip.begin()
    print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
    print('System initialized...', current_time)
    print()
    button_red_led.blink(2, 2)  # Initial red to show startup is off.
    if not args.clear:
        print('Use "-c" argument to clear LEDs on exit')

    try:

        while True:
            button.when_pressed = pressed
            pir.when_pressed = pir_active

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if args.clear:
            colorwipe(strip, Color(0, 0, 0))
            button_red_led.off()
            button_blue_led.off()
            button_green_led.off()
            print('Program ended, light is off')
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you've already got some button input working, presumably you already know how to do that. The issue you've got is the way you implement the timer is by calling the "sleep" function. During that time python can't do anything else. It's busy sleeping. This is what's known as a "blocking" call. And to be clear it's absolutely perfectly fine...unless you want to do something else during that time...like checking the status of a button.

The non-blocking way of doing this kind of sleep basically takes on the form of:

1. when the pir sensor activates record the current time
2. every x seconds do: current_time - pir_activated_time and check to see if that is greater than your timeout

this combined with using the "when_pressed()" method of the button instead of the "wait_for_pressed()" should get you what you want. See docs for how to use the when_pressed() method: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button

Comment: I'll sit down with it this weekend and rework it.

Comment: That did work. I did work it out and the project is still in refining and expanding mode.